# Setters/Getters for a nested Object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I know how to set Custom Setters & Getters in Javascript using `Object.defineProperty`

My intention with the following code snippet is to be able to hit the setter function whenever a property nested value inside the globalProject object is modified.

```
var ClassA = function () {
    this.globalProject = {
        a: "DEFAULT VALUE",
        b: null
    };
    this.LastSavedProject = {};

};

Object.defineProperty(ClassA.prototype, 'globalProject', {
    get: function () {
        console.log("OVERRIDE");
        return this._flag;
    },
    set: function (val) {
        console.log("EDITING A DEEP VALUE")
        this._flag = val;
    },
});


var obj = new ClassA();

obj.globalProject.a = "HELLO WORLD" //Should get "EDITING A DEEP VALUE" in the console.
```

I imagine what is happening is that the getter method is being called and returning a reference to an object I want to modify. Because of that the setter is never being called since I am modifying a reference to a nested value and not the property I have a setter on.

Can anyone help me sort out this issue? Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7paqnza/

Comment: I'm also very interested in a way to do that. I hope someone has an answer

Answer (score 5):

When you execute `obj.globalProject.a = "HELLO WORLD"`, you simply see "OVERRIDE" in the console because you are getting the value of `obj.globalProject` and setting the value of its data member `a`.

You do not see "EDITING A DEEP VALUE" in the console because you never set `globalProject` to refer to a different object, you simply changed one of the underlying object's data members. If you executed something like `obj.globalProject = null`, however, you would see "EDITING A DEEP VALUE" printed to the console, for you would have changed what object `obj.globalProject` refers to. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7paqnza/1/

Comment: I understand that. How would you suggest that I achieve what I am trying to? Thanks

Comment: The setter is never being called because you are never calling it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm building an undo system. The project is edited from many different places and I want to monitor every change so I can record them in an array and apply/remove them in sequence. @PaulD

Comment: @user3583341: did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

What @PaulDapolito said is exactly correct. We are not calling the setter of globalObject when deep object is set. I have updated the code to add setters for deep object and now it calls the inner object setters. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sjLLbqLc/4/

For this particular question, we can do the insert operation inside the **GlobalProject** class setters.

I am late to the party, but I hope this helps someone who lands up here in search of it.

```js
var ClassA = function() {
  this.globalProject = new GlobalProject(); // this sets global object
  // you can initilaize your default values here to the global object. But you need the new GlobalProject() which    will create the object with setters and getters.
};

Object.defineProperty(ClassA.prototype, 'globalProject', {
  get: function() {
    return this._flag;
  },
  set: function(val) {
    console.log("Setting global object");
    this._flag = val;
  },
});

var GlobalProject = function() {
  Object.defineProperty(GlobalProject.prototype, "a", {
    get: function() {
      return this._a;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      console.log("Seting deep object");
      this._a = value;
    }
  });
  Object.defineProperty(GlobalProject.prototype, "b", {
    get: function() {
      return this._b;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      this._b = value;
    }
  });
};


var obj = new ClassA();

obj.globalProject.a = "HELLO WORLD";// this sets the inner object
```

Comment: That's making a getter & setter just for `a` and `b`, not for all possible children.